# How does Royden define the mapping function from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb N$ while proving Countability of Rational numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

While defining the funtion from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb N$, Royden uses the following approach.
Define a function $g:\Bbb Q \to \Bbb N$, such that

1. $g(0) = 0$
2. $g(p/q) = (p+q)^2 + q$, if $x = p/q > 0$ and $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime natural numbers
3. $g(x) = -g(-x)$ if $x < 0$.

$0$ is not in $\Bbb N$,  $-g(-x)$ always returns a negative value

How is this a mapping from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb N$?

Comment: Then Royden had a typo, he's defining a bijection Q to Z, which of course is just as good as proving countability

Comment: Ohh but when we are checking for countability we are finding a one to one correspondence to Natural numbers. From the flow in which he has written he is trying to define a function from Q to N only

Comment: Just append $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb N$, $x\mapsto |3x+1|$

Comment: @Sri Aditya When you are proving a set is countable, you must exhibit a bijection between it and any countable set. $\mathbb{Z}$ is seen to be countable.

Comment: @MichaelBarz Yes this is true...but i was wondering why he has explicitly mentioned Q to N, but I understood the point